# Meaning of "You might call him the Susan Lucci of chemistry"

Tags: meaning

The passage below is from "[To Be a Genius, Think Like a 94-Year-Old](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/07/opinion/sunday/to-be-a-genius-think-like-a-94-year-old.html?_r=0)", NYT

> A study of Nobel physics laureates found that, since the 1980s, they have made their discoveries, on average, at age 50. The study also found that the peak of creativity for Nobel winners is getting higher every year. For many years, oddsmakers have predicted that Dr. Goodenough would win the Nobel Prize, but so far the call from Stockholm has not come. **You might call him the Susan Lucci of chemistry.**

I don't see any correlation between Dr.Goodenough and Susan Lucci, as Susan earned her fame at her young age. The only common thing is both are old aged persons. I have asked my teacher about the meaning of the last sentence, and he has no idea.  I am not clear about the meaning of the last sentence and the word "chemistry".

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network; it is history-of-science- rather than language-focused.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth which site should I go to ask such questions? I see from top line here written "English Language & Usage". I am very sad since you proposed to closed my question, although the happiness from the previous help I got for my language questions. I don't want to go to wrong place and trouble you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth When I click"ask question ", it prompt "title","tag" for me to choose from the list, I can see clearly all the tag options are language related such as "meaning ","grammar ",etymology "etc. I don't thing I go wrong place. Here is not history-of -science place. Are you wrong?

Comment: Apparently, Susan Lucci is an actress rather than a scientist. // Looking for a connection between the lives of Dr.Goodenough and Susan Lucci is not connected with English language and usage. // If 'the Susan Lucci of' is becoming an accepted idiom, then looking up "the Susan Lucci of" should be done by the questioner. [Proz.com](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/English/cinema_film_tv_drama/5419478-the_susan_lucci_of.html) seems to have the answer. // I'm sorry, I can't think of any website that would specialise in character comparisons. But there are many general Q and A sites on the web.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It does relate to English language and usage. It should go to tag of"meaning -in-context". Finding out why the author correlates these two persons help us understand the article and the language better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I really appreciate you! How do you find it so easily from proz.com? It is awesome! From the reference there given, I also get it from urban dictionary.com! This is what I what! You are so helpful today for me to solved this question! You made my day!❤️Heartiest thanks from me, Shanghai,China

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you also guided me an additional useful website (proz.com) which is precious resources for me to solve my English questions when I read English articles. By the way, I am a Chinese trying to learn English every day.

Comment: Janet, our sister site ELL was set up for the sort of questions learners of English might have. ELU is aimed rather at those more proficient in the language. // In this case, the answer below has 'The parallel **appears to be** [bolding mine] that it took both a long time to achieve the success they seemed predestined for.' I myself had never heard of Susan Lucci. ELU is targeted at discussing standard usages, not candidate words and expressions that may one day make it into standard dictionaries / dictionaries of idioms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ok, I will go to English Language & Learner, which It fits. I am surprised that you didn't hear about Susan Lucci who is a long-time famous actress,as I assume you a native English speaker. You can get to know about her on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Lucci.    Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't think the people at ELL will consider this primarily an idiomatic-usage-of-language based question either. And you already have the (apparently correct) answer below, given by 0xFEE1DEAD.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth for this question, I have got the answer from 0xFEE1DEAD, yours From Proz.com and from which I got referred from urban dictionary is a perfect proof. I don't go anywhere else for this question. For further articles, my questions would be same language level, I will try to go ELL in case I can't solve it myself. For your information, a group of our persons are studying together. The question got proof from the dictionary explanation and solved make everyone happy!Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parallel appears to be that it took both a long time to achieve the success they seemed predestined for.

> Lucci was nominated for the Outstanding Lead Actress in a Drama Series Emmy for her work on All My Children almost every year since 1978. When Lucci did not win the award after several consecutive nominations, her image in the media began to be lampooned, as she became notoriously synonymous with never winning an Emmy. [...] After 18 failed nominations, she finally won in 1999. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Lucci

Comment: Yes, for a while in the eighties/nineties Susan Lucci was widely synonymous with *always a nominee, never a winner*. The reference is somewhat outdated now, but I know I've used it within the past decade as there's not really a better more recent analogy.